# infinite intersection of orbit of bijective map, part 2

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a countable infinite set, $T$ be a bijective map of $A$, $U$ be a non-empty proper subset of $A$. Suppose that $\cap_{n=-N}^{\infty}T^{n}(U)$ and $\cap_{n=-\infty}^{N}T^{n}(U)$ are non-empty for all natural number $N$, can the intersection $\cap_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}T^{n}(U)$ be empty?

I think that is possible, as the answer of this question ([infinite intersection of orbit of bijective map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4302489/infinite-intersection-of-orbit-of-bijective-map)) suggested, but I am not sure since the condition is strengthen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.  Take $A = \mathbb{Z}$, $T :x \mapsto x + 1$, $U = \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$.  Then $\bigcap_{n = -N}^\infty T^n(U) = (-\infty, -N)$ and $\bigcap_{n = -\infty}^N T^n(U) = (N, \infty)$, but $\bigcap_{n = -\infty}^\infty T^n(U) = \emptyset$.